# Email notifications on new articles / Automatic newsletter

Tags: joomla-3.x, emails

I need a way to automatically send an e-mail to a list of subscribers

- either whenever a new article is published, with a link to that article
- or periodically, with a list of new articles

I did a research and found some extension that partly serve this purpose ([J!MailAlerts](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/marketing/mailing-a-distribution-lists/j-mailalerts/), [Minitek Content Notification](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/marketing/newsletter/content-notifications/)), but I am not quite satisfied with them (difficult to subscribe to more than one category, impossible to import mail list. Though they offer notifications for guests, they seem to be more oriented towards registered members).

Also it the big newsletter components AcyMailing and JNews seem to offer an Auto-newsletter or Smart Newsletter feature, but only in their more expensive variants. And I don't want to pay some $80, when I don't really need a full-blown professional newsletter, only a simple notification on new content.

So do you know about any better alternatives?

Comment: you can develop it and pay no money for it... apart of that, there is also services like MailChimp that will provide newsletter subscriptions features and can automate campaigns with a croty-type schedule to fetch new articles from your rss feeds

Comment: I think I am not experienced enough to develop my own, though I'd like to learn it when I have more time (I have already altered some extensions to suit my needs).
But here I came to the same conclusion, I think RSS feed + MailChimp will do the best job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that none of the extensions I tried has the features I need, as they are either focused primarily to notify registered users of changes in certain category (such as J!MailAlerts and Minitek Content Notification I mentioned in my question) or just newsletter extensions without any way to automatically send notifications (at least in their basic versions).

So, in my opinion, instead of Joomla extensions, the better way is to use RSS feed of the site (or more precisely featured articles) and MailChimp's RSS-Driven Campaign. It is free (for up to 2000 subscribers) and has all the features I need.

I faced some problems with customizing the feed, but for that I found the useful [MVC Override](https://github.com/ghazal/plg_mvcoverride) plugin.